# React Native Expo (SDK 49) with TypeScript: Encountering `AbortError: Aborted`

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation, react-typescript, expo-router

I'm developing a React Native application using Expo SDK 49 and TypeScript. My application includes an authentication flow where I use a state variable `user` to manage the user's authentication status and navigate between screens.

Here's a simplified version of my `AuthProvider` component:

```js
export function AuthProvider({children }: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  const rootSegment = useSegments()[0];
  const router = useRouter();
  const [user, setUser] = useState<string | undefined>("");  

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user === undefined) return;

    if (!user && rootSegment !== "(auth)") {
      router.replace("/(auth)/Onboarding");
    } else if (user && rootSegment !== "(app)") {
      router.replace("/");
    }
  }, [user, rootSegment]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        signIn: () => {
          setUser("Hatem");
        },
        signOut: () => {
          setUser("");
        },
      }}>
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

When the `user` state is empty, the router navigates to the `Onboarding` screen. If there's a user (i.e., the `user` state is not empty), the router navigates to the root directory.

However, I keep encountering an `AbortError: Aborted` error when the `user` state changes. The error seems to occur after the user is set to an empty string and the app tries to navigate to the `Onboarding` screen.

Here's a sample of the error messages I'm seeing in the console:

```
ERROR  got error [AbortError: Aborted]
ERROR  got error [AbortError: Aborted]
ERROR  got error [AbortError: Aborted]
...
```

From the outermost `_layout.tsx`

```js
function RootLayoutNav() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Slot />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

I've tried changing the initial state of `user` to different values (`null`, `undefined`, an empty string), but the error persists. I've also checked that the `Onboarding` screen and the root directory have components to render.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any suggestions on how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!